# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: typescript, frontend, tauri

I was trying to learn Tauri with vanilla Typescript code.

For some reason, vscode say that `event.key` and `foo_input.value` are not properties of `Event`. But running the Tauri nothing wrong happened.

```js
const foo_input = document.querySelector(".foo");

foo_input?.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if (event.key !== 'Enter') return;

    console.log(foo_input.value);
});
```

```
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339)

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

this is the element with the `.foo` class:

```html
<body>
  <main>
    ...
    <input type="text" class="foo" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
    ...
  </main>
</body>
```

Actually I'm was using the `KeyboardEvent`, so I tried to type the `event`.

```js
const foo_input: Element | null = document.querySelector(".foo");

foo_input?.addEventListener("keydown", (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.key !== 'Enter') return;

    console.log(foo_input.value);
});
```

This gave me another error:

```
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: keyof ElementEventMap, listener: (this: Element, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"keydown"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ElementEventMap'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(event: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.ts(2769)
```

I am new in typescript and I dont program often in front-end, so I dont know what is happening, specially because I basically copied some solutions from some questions here on stackoverflow.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: Is that error in the console or error from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: You can tell TypeScript what element type it is: https://tsplay.dev/Ndao0m

Comment: Kevin M. Mansour, it was from Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of the element as a generic parameter to `document.querySelector`, so that TypeScript understands what events and properties there are.

```
const foo_input = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(".foo");
```